# pushing and pulling from remote git repo works but it is empty on remote server

Tags: linux, git

I have a linux server with ssh and git installed.

I created a folder on the root directory and changed its owner to `mike` to avoid giving out root passwords to anyone.

```
sudo mkdir /GitRepos
sudo chown mike:mike /GitRepos
```

Then I created an empty repo, and set it to `bare`, otherwise pushing to this repo does not work (I tried!!)

```
mkdir test.git
cd test.git
git init
git config core.bare true
```

I then used another machine (Windows) to clone the newly created repo:

```
git clone ssh://mike@myLinuxServer/GitRepos/test.git
```

and that worked fine, I got an empty repo as expected.
I added some files and committed the change.

```
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push origin master
```

Pushing works fine. I even deleted the entire repo from the local machine, and tried to clone it again.

```
cd ..
rd test /s
git clone ssh://mike@myLinuxServer/GitRepos/test.git
```

It worked fine and I got all of the files.
When I went to the remote Linux machine, I listed the files inside `test.git` and found it empty.
Where did the files go?
How can the repo receive pushes and give out files for pulls without storing the files in the repo?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+difference+bare+non-bare+repositories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files are stored in the remote repository's database. You cannot expect that the files themselves appear in the remote repository, in particular not when you declare it as *bare*.

The way you initialized the bare remote repository is very unusual. You should have done it simply like this:

```
cd /GitRepos
git init --bare test.git
```

Answer (score 2):

The repository on the server is considered as a `bare` repo as you ran `git config core.bare true`. A more common way to initialize a bare repo is `git init --bare test.git` or `mkdir test.git;cd test.git;git init --bare`. The difference between `git init test.git;cd test.git;git config core.bare true` and `git init --bare test.git` lies in the directory structure. The former creates the worktree(`test.git`) and the database(`test.git/.git`) but forbids the worktree then. The latter creates only the database(`test.git`), without the worktree from the beginning.

A bare repository does not have an active worktree by default, which means you can't check out files from any revision in a bare repository. Although you can create extra worktrees with `git worktree add`, it's quite rare and may behave not so well as a non-bare repository with extra worktrees. All the revisions are stored as compressed data in the database. You can use commands to read the data, like `git show master` or `git ls-tree -r master`.

> > otherwise pushing to this repo does not work (I tried!!)

It's partially true. You can't push to a non-bare repository when you try to update a branch which has been checked out in the remote repository. If the branch you try to update is not checked out or does not exist yet, you can push to update or create it. With `git config receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore` or `git config receive.denyCurrentBranch warn`, you can even update such branch. But in practice, we always use bare repositories to preserve revision data.